# How to render a field collection without default divs?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I want to output a field collection using `dl`, `dt` and `dd` tags. The collection has two fields - `field_heading` and `field_text`. I want each field_heading to be a dt, each `field_text` to be a `dd` and to wrap the whole set in a `dl`.

I have achieved this by overriding `field--my-collection--my-content-type.tpl.php` and the `field--my-field.tpl.php` for the heading and text fields.

The problem is, a `div` is being generated on each item in the field collection (by the field collection module I believe). (`div class="field-collection-view clearfix view-mode-full"`) This div wraps the heading and text elements together. The div is therefore inserted inside the `dl` but before the `dt`. This is a problem because the `dt` needs to be a direct child of the `dl`.

Is there a way to render the field collection without this div?

**field--my-collection--my-content-type.tpl.php**

```
<dl class = 'accordion'>
<?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item){ ?>
    <?php print render($item); ?>
<?php } ?>
</dl>
```

**field--field-heading.tpl.php**

```
<dt>
<?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item){
    print render($item);
} ?>
</dt>
```

**field--field-text.tpl.php**

```
<dd>
<?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item){
    print render($item);
} ?>
</dd>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to override [theme_field_collection_view](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!field_collection!field_collection.module/function/theme_field_collection_view/7) theme function in your template.php .

Comment: After reading [this issue](https://drupal.org/node/1157794) I was not aware that it is already possible to theme the wrapper. But [theme_field_collection_view](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!field_collection!field_collection.module/function/theme_field_collection_view/7) worked great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a file "field-collection-view.tpl.php" which you put in your theme folder

Content of the file:

`<?php
  print $element['#children'];
?>`

If you'd want it to output exactly what it does now (I know that you don't), you'd have this content:

`<?php
  print '<div' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $element['#children'] . '</div>';
?>`